# Match parameters to method signature

Tags: java, spring, reflection

I have a `Method` and a `List<Object>` of parameters for the method to be invoked with. However the list of parameters may not be in the correct order and may include too many/not enough parameters that match the method signature.

Before I reinvent the wheel, does a function exist to invoke the method with the list of parameters I have and it match, as best it can, the parameters to the method signature...maybe something in Spring?

Answer (score 1):

No, any implementation to solve your problem would need external information that only the provider of the `Method` and `List<Object>` would have.

With a method like

```
void method (String name, String city, String parent) {}
```

and a `List`

```
"Sotirios", "New York", "Alexander"
```

where would each argument go in the `Method#invoke(..)`?

Only you can know that information.

Comment: Ah i didn't think about that. My example would only ever have differing types. Guess I will write something...

Comment: @Cheetah The most you can do (without actually knowing the order) is a best-effort matching the types (considering inheritance too). You could rank orders and choose the top ranking one.

Answer (score -2):

You can either pass the list to your method directly or use [method overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

method overloading can be useful, but wouldn't really be an option if your arguments are out of order. If you can sort your list of objects beforehand then it may be an option.

In my mind however, the simplest way to pass your list of objects is to pass the list itself instead of trying to break it up beforehand. In this case you would need to write out your logic to break up the list once inside the method. This case would also provide you with more testing capability to find out what exactly is contained in your list.